# How to design an optimal LLR Quantization of LLR for LDPC Decoding under AWGN channel using BPSK(Known quantization boundaries)?

Tags: discrete-signals, quantization, ldpc

Recently I met an optimazition problem, i.e., finding an optimal quantizer which maps floating point LLRs to integers of range $-11,\ldots +11$, where the quantizer boundaries have been calculated out.

For example, let the quantizer boundaries and corresponding LLRs be:

| quantizer upper bound | float LLR |
| --- | --- |
| -0.25 | 70.68 |
| -0.16 | 67.20 |
| -0.09 | 6.15 |
| 0.00 | 1.25 |
| +0.09 | -1.25 |
| +0.16 | -6.15 |
| +0.25 | -67.20 |
| +$\infty$ | -70.68 |

How to design an optimal uniform or non-uniform quantizer which have the best frame error performance of LDPC decoder?

The quantizer should satisfy the following conditions:

1. The quantizer should not be too complex;
2. The quantized LLR should not have repeat values: for example, for above example, quantizer outputs are: $+11, +7, +5, +1, -1, -5, -7, -11$.

Comment: "not too complex" really is ambiguous. Please define, precisely, what you mean. LDPC decoders are typically iterative, and its up to the designer and user to decide how many iterations to do. So, you *really* need to be clear about what you intend this to mean.

Comment: Your second requirement potentially conflicts with a uniform design and limited size of the integer range, which probably is the point of all this.